# postgresql 12 doesn't allow me to create a local server

Tags: postgresql, config

I am working with postgresql on a remote server via a vpn connection.

My debian buster postgresql 12 installation doesn't allow me to create a local server and ask me to verify I'm allowed to connect to the unix domain socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Pgadmin says:

> timeout expired

```
su
Password: 
root@mycomputer:/home/me# su - postgres
postgres@mycomputer:~$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: File o directory non esistente
    Verifica che il server locale sia in funzione e che
    accetti connessioni sul socket di dominio Unix "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

What is the file missing?
Can you help me?

Comment: How exactly did you install Postgres? Did you run `initdb` on your local computer after installing Postgres? Did you verify that the Postgres service is running?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sequence of commands of:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/creating-cluster.html

root# mkdir /usr/local/pgsql
root# chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql
root# su postgres
postgres$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

The last reply is:
bash: pg_ctl: comando non trovato (command not found)

Answer (score 0):

I purged postegresql* and pgadmin4
I installed back everything
psql starts from terminal but

mycomputer@user:$ pgadmin4
pgadmin4
Python path:  "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"
Python Home:  ""
Webapp path:  "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"

- Serving Flask app "pgadmin" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
  and finally says

"The application server could not be contacted."